# Under what conditions does a classpath mapping get added to bootstrap.js by Sencha Cmd?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-cmd

I'm using Sencha Cmd 5.1.3.61 against Ext. 4.2.3.

My classpath is kind of weird. So far as I can tell just about every one of my non-boilerplate non-ext classes needs to have a classpath mapping in bootstrap.js. At run-time in dev-mode the Loader can't find a class called myapp.header.HeaderPanel. This is because no entry was created for that class at build-time in bootstrap.js. This strikes me as strange because 1) an empty alternate name mapping is created for that class and 2) that class is successfully pulled into ${buildDir}/testing/app.js. So clearly Sencha cmd is finding it ok.

I'm wondering, under what conditions does a classpath mapping get added to bootstrap.js? I.e. how does cmd decide when to create a classpath mapping and when not to?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running `sencha app refresh` or `sencha app build` then all of your bootstrap files (`.js`, `.json`) should be re-generated with everything you've told the application about.

Be sure you've added the necessary `requires`, `extends` or `uses` references -- those are how Sencha Cmd knows what classes are necessary. See the [blog post](https://sencha.guru/2015/05/21/requiring-classes/) by Mitchell Simoens explaining this.